# Axiom of Choice: Family of non-empty sets mutually disjoint or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have noticed that the family of non-empty sets referred to in statements of the Axiom of Choice is sometimes required to be mutually disjoint, and sometimes not. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes no real difference: the two statements are equivalent. The version with pairwise disjoint sets is conceptually simpler, while the other is slightly easier to apply, since it's superficially more general.

Comment: The simpler version allows the possibility of choosing the same element more than once. I take it then that this never presents are real problem.

Comment: @Dan: That's correct. Assume either version, and one can quite easily prove the other. If $\{A_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda\}$ is a family of sets, $\{A\alpha\times\{\alpha\}:\alpha\in\Lambda\}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint sets.

Comment: Gah. That should be $A_\alpha\times\{\alpha\}$, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Let me add on Brian's answer.

> If $A$ is a family of non-empty sets then there is a function $F\colon A\to\bigcup A$ such that $F(a)\in a$ for all $a\in A$.

This is the usual axiom of choice, we didn't require that $A$ is a pairwise disjoint family here.

> If $A$ is a family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty sets then there is $C$ such that for all $a\in A$, $|a\cap C|=1$.

This statement is sometimes the given formulation of the axiom of choice, and here we have to require that $A$ is a pairwise disjoint family. Otherwise $\{\{0,1\},\{1,2\},\{0,2\}\}$ will have no such $C$.

The two are of course equivalent. But looking just at the assumption in the statement one requires disjointness, and one doesn't.