# Validity of the axiom of choice under different definitions of pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, axiom-of-choice

I've been reading different books, and I found two slightly different definitions for a family of sets $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ to be "Pairwise disjoint" or simply "Disjoint" mainly:

> **Definition 1** Let $I$ be a nonempty set, and let  $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of nonempty sets indexed by $I$, This family is **pairwise disjoint** if $i,j\in I$ such that $i \neq j$  and $A_i \neq A_j$ imply that $A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing$.

---

> **Definition 2** Let $I$ be a nonempty set, and let  $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of nonempty sets indexed by $I$, This family is **pairwise disjoint** if   $A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing$ for all $i,j\in I$ such that $i \neq j$ .

The subtle different is that **definition 1** allows that the family may have different indexes for the same set. Now I've been reading about the axiom of choice, and I found the following formulation on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052543/axiom-of-choice-family-of-non-empty-sets-mutually-disjoint-or-not)

> If $A$ is a family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty sets then there is $C$ such that for all $a\in A$, $|a\cap C|=1$.

**My first question**: Is this formulation of the axiom of choice valid for both definition of *pairwise disjoint family of sets* in the sense that this formulation would remain equivalent to others statements like *Zorn's lema, Existing of a choice function, etc*. Or in the sense that we could find a counter example if we chose one of the definitions. Furthermore, **my Second question is**; if I found some others statements referring to "Pairwise disjoint family of sets" without specifying if we are using defnition one or two what should I do?.

Comment: I find both of these books odd; there's no reason to get indexing mixed up in the notion of pairwise disjointness.

Comment: Definition 1) is not accepted by  Mathematicians.  We do  not consider $\{A.A,A,...\}$ as  a disjoint collection of sets if $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - But a constant function $i\mapsto A$ for $i\in I$ is perfectly well accepted, which is what an indexed family can do.

Comment: A not complicated definition:  a (not empty) collection C of (not empty) sets is pairwise disjoint when for all distinct A,B in C, A and B are disjoint.

Comment: if we have an equivalence relation $R$ on a set $X$, then I'm sure we all think that  $X/R = \{ [x] \mid x\in X \}$is a collection of "Pairwise disjoint sets" but what would you say of ,$X/R = \{[x]\}_{x\in X}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen "pairwise disjoint family indexed by $I$" used to mean Definition 1; it always means Definition 2 in my experience.  Note though that you can also talk about a pairwise disjoint family where "family" just means "set" rather than "indexed set".  In that case, Definition 1 is what it means for the set (*not* the indexed set) $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ to be pairwise disjoint.  Incidentally, I strongly recommend not using the same notation for a set and an indexed set; I would use $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ for the indexed set (which is really a function with domain $I$) and $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ for the set (which is the image of that function).  On a related note, if you are using "family" to mean indexed set rather than just set, your statement of the axiom of choice should be

> If $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty sets then there is $C$ such that for all $i\in I$, $|A_i\cap C|=1$.

The version you stated cannot be used with either of your definitions since neither definition defines what it means for a set $A$ (rather than an indexed set $(A_i)_{i\in I}$) to be a pairwise disjoint family.  (Of course, you can make such a definition, and get a third version of the axiom of choice.  It is trivial to see that this third version is equivalent to the axiom of choice using Definition 2, since given any non-indexed family $A$ you can make it an indexed family by the identity map $A\to A$ (that is, you take $I=A$ and $A_i=i$).)

In any case, the axiom of choice for Definition 1 is equivalent for the axiom of choice for Definition 2.  The forward direction is trivial; for the reverse direction, assume the axiom of choice for Definition 2 and let $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint sets by Definition 1.  Let $J=\{A_i:i\in I\}$ and consider the indexed set $(B_j)_{j\in J}$ defined by $B_j=j$.

I claim $(B_j)_{j\in J}$ is a pairwise disjoint family according to Definition 2.  Indeed, suppose $j,j'\in J$ and $j\neq j'$.  By definition of $J$, there exist $i,i'\in I$ such that $j=A_i$ and $j'=A_{i'}$.  Then $A_i\neq A_{i'}$ and $i\neq i'$ (since $i\mapsto A_i$ is a function), so since $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ satisfies Definition 1, $A_i\cap A_{i'}=\emptyset$.  But $A_i=j=B_j$ and $A_{i'}=j'=B_{j'}$, so $B_j\cap B_j=\emptyset$.

Thus by the axiom of choice for Definition 2, there exists a set $C$ such that $|B_j\cap C|=1$ for each $j\in J$.  Now for any $i\in I$, let $j=A_i$, so $A_i=B_j$.  We thus see that $|A_i\cap C|=|B_j\cap C|=1$.  So, this set $C$ also has the required property for the family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$.

Comment: Marvelous this is exactly what I was waiting for an answer, really nice trick when defining $J$. I also appreciate the notation corrections. Thank you for your time and now  I'm going to add some of the sources from where I extract the "odd" definition.